# Pintool debugging error in GDB: Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap

Tags: debugging, gdb, intel-pin

I'm attempting to debug a Pintool, and encountered an error during the process: `Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.`

I'm trying to debug the Pintool using the instructions provided on the official Pin website, specifically in the "Tips for Debugging a Pintool" section. I followed these instructions accordingly. The issue occurred when I set a breakpoint in gdb and continued.

Here's my terminal output leading up to the error:

```
(gdb) b champsim_tracer.cpp:160
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7f1d79cb48a3: file champsim_tracer.cpp, line 160.

(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring. If anyone has an understanding of this issue, I would appreciate guidance on how to address and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

(This might feel a little silly, but I had the same issue)

When I attach gdb to PIN, it always triggers a SIGTRAP at the start, have you tried simply resuming the execution from there?